# Switch and lambda in Python

Tags: python-2.7, lambda

I’m writing a Gimp plug-in in Python. While looking for a switch statement I found an example with `lambda`. Yes, I can use `if … elif` but I want to learn to use `lambda`.

I’m calculating the horizontal offset for cropping an image. I have the width I need to trim off in `width_to_trim` (actual width minus desired width).

I have the mode of trimming in `h_align`; this can take the values `HALIGN_LEFT`, `HALIGN_CENTRE` and `HALIGN_RIGHT`, which have already been defined; these are basically 0, 1 and 2 respectively, but I’ll use “constants” for clarity.

So, if I’m aligning to the left I’ll offset the cropping at 0, if at the centre I’ll start half way through the image, and if I want to align to the right I’ll have to offset the cropping at the whole extra bit.

Here’s my code (now edited to include commas and an argument for my lambda at `get`):

```
# calculate horizontal position for cropping
switcher = {
    HALIGN_LEFT: 0,
    HALIGN_CENTRE: lambda x: x/2,
    HALIGN_RIGHT: lambda x: x,
}
crop_x = switcher.get(h_align)(width_to_trim)
```

When I print off `crop_x`, I get:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x1048eca28>
```

So clearly I was left with a function, not with a value. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider having a comma after each dict element inside switcher

Comment: Indeed @SwadhikarC! It’s still not doing what I want. Still not all good; when I print crop_x it still has a lambda in it. I changed the get line to `crop_x = switcher.get(h_align)(width_to_trim)`, but still the same issue.

Comment: Did you erase the .pyc file?

Comment: Also, your code will break on `HALIGN_LEFT`.

Comment: What you describe is pretty much impossible.There must be a typo, like `switcher.get(h_align, width_to_trim)`, or you are printing not what you think you are printing.

Comment: @tobias_k, the second argument of `get`supplies a default value in case the dictionary doesn’t have the specified key: so, `switcher.get(h_align, width_to_trim)` means “return the value for the key `h_align` in `switcher`, but if you can’t find one then return `width_to_trim`” – which is not what I want. I am sure that `switcher` has the value I want, so I don’t need to pass a default value.

Comment: @JúlioReis I know, I did not mean that you should change it to that, but that that's maybe how it looks now.

Comment: @tobias_k I was so happy I learnt what `.get` does that I just had to tell the world! :) Anyway, my answer below works for me.

Answer (score 0):

My switch code works like this:

```
switcher = {
    HALIGN_LEFT: lambda x: 0,
    HALIGN_CENTRE: lambda x: x/2,
    HALIGN_RIGHT: lambda x: x,
}
crop_x = (switcher.get(h_align))(width_to_trim)
```

My `get`returns a function, and then when I wrap that in parenthesis and pass it an argument it will assign the label `crop_x` to the calculated value, not to the lambda.

Also, I could not simply assign 0 in the case of `HALIGN_LEFT`: I have to assign a function that returns 0, or else when I assign `crop_x` I’d get an error message because I’d be treating an `int` as if it were a function.